# Verifying NHibernate Mappings with NDBUnit

Tags: nhibernate, ndbunit

I'm currently using NHibernate in a project and am using NDBUnit to populate a DB with data for my unit tests. What I'd like to do is verify the XML used by NDBUnit against the class instances returned back by NHibernate when I load the data.

Seems like I could use reflection on the classes to get all the properties, and then lookup those column values in the NDBUnit XML dataset. I'm just not sure if I'm reinventing the wheel or if there's a better alternative to verifying that all my NHibernate mappings are correct?

Answer (score 0):

Check out PersistenceSpecification in Fluent NHibernate. There is nothing in that class that relies on Fluent NHibernate and I've used it before when testing plain old NHibernate hbm.xml files.

http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Persistence_specification_testing

For example you can write tests like this:

```
[Test]
public void CanCorrectlyMapEmployee()
{
    new PersistenceSpecification<Employee>(session)
        .CheckProperty(c => c.Id, 1)
        .CheckProperty(c => c.FirstName, "John")
        .CheckProperty(c => c.LastName, "Doe")
        .VerifyTheMappings();
}
```

Highly recommended.

Comment: This might work if you're using an installed database, however if you're using an in-memory database (e.g. sqlite), which is something I advocate for integration tests, I don't think this test would be particularly useful. The reason for this is because the in-memory database would be created 'from' the mappings and a test to check if you can insert a record is simply testing the NHibernate ORM itself.